# No keyword with name 'Open Application' found

Tags: python, pycharm, appium, robotframework, robot

**
I am getting this error, I tried clean installation, how can I fix it?

```
    **** Settings ****
Library    AppiumLibrary
*** Variables ***
${REMOTE_URL}    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
${PLATFORM_NAME}    Android
${platformVersion}    10.0
${DEVICE_NAME}    Xiaomi Redmi Note 7
${APP_PACKAGE}    mobi.appcent.apponte    # Replace this with your app's package name
${APP_ACTIVITY}    mobi.appcent.apponte.ui.activity.login.LoginActivity    # Replace this with your app's main activity
*** Test Cases ***
Open and Close Application
    Open Application   http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android    platformVersion =10.0    deviceName=Xiaomi Redmi Note 7   appPackage=mobi.appcent.apponte    appActivity=mobi.appcent.apponte.ui.activity.login.LoginActivity**
    No keyword with name 'Open Application' found.
00:00:00.001KEYWORD Open Application   http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub    automationName=${ANDROID_AUTOMATION_NAME}    platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}    platformVersion=${platformVersion}    app=C:\\Users\\alica\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject5\\test/storage/emulated/0/base.apk    appPackage=mobi.appcent.apponte    appActivity=mobi.appcent.apponte.ui.activity.login.LoginActivity***
```

Comment: you are getting error Where ?

Comment: "Open Application   http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android    platformVersion =10.0    deviceName=Xiaomi Redmi Note 7   appPackage=mobi.appcent.apponte    appActivity=mobi.appcent.apponte.ui.activity.login.LoginActivity**
    No keyword with name 'Open Application' found." I am working in .robot file this is the error message.

Comment: It could be that there is something with the AppiumLibrary installation on your side. For example, it could be installed globally, and your project could use a virtual environment or vice versa. Or could not be installed at all. Also, carefully check the console output of your test case; there could be other errors or warnings that could cause errors in the library import.

Comment: No other errors appear in the log output.
I installed the library from the pycharm terminal, pip install --upgrade robotframework-appiumlibrary with this code.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this setup and it is working fine for me:

```
AppiumLibrary.Open Application    http://localhost:4723
...                               platformName=Android
...                               appium:automationName=UiAutomator2
...                               deviceName=Pixel_6_Pro_API_34
...                               appPackage=com.name.ofMyApp
...                               appActivity=com.name.ofMyApp.MainActivity
...                               appium:noReset=false
```

I am using `robotframework-appiumlibrary    2.0.0`

Comment: Did you install via cmd or in your python project?